# Store json in variable

Tags: c#, json

I am trying tracking but the json which i get in response is not in correct format. So i want to replace it with something to make it in a correct format.
I want to store returned json data in some string variable. NOTE: I want to store json as it is and I dont want to deserialize it. Is there any way to do so?
This is the tracking link

http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/reverse.php?format=json&json_callback=renderExampleThreeResults&lat=30.718263&lon=76.694216

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but the json which i get in response is not in correct format. So i want to replace it with something to make it in a correct format

It is *[jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)*, to get a json response just remove the `json_callback=renderExampleThreeResults` parameters from the url.

New url is:

http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/reverse.php?format=json&lat=30.718263&lon=76.694216

Comment: Wow.. I appreciate your reply. Thanx a lot. It helped me a lot

Answer (score 2):

Just save response in string anywhere you want:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/reverse.php?format=json&json_callback=renderExampleThreeResults&lat=30.718263&lon=76.694216");
 response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
 string jsonValue = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

In jsonValue variable you have json.